# Overwriting zend form checkbox

Tags: php, zend-framework, checkbox

I have a problem with the zend form checkbox.

```
$this->addElement('checkbox', 'languages', array(
        'label'         => 'Languages',
        'class'         => 'check_1',
        'name'          => 'checkset',
        'checkedValue'  => '1',
        'uncheckedValue'=> '0'
    ));
```

I made this checkbox and overwritten the checkedValue and uncheckedValue but when I debug it, it has totally different values:

```
$values = $form_duplicate->getValues();
        var_dump($values);
```

This is the result:

```
["languages"]=> string(1) "0"
```

I can't understand where is the problem. I looked up on the zend documentation page and this is how it must be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, but you can use the `setCheckedValue` and `setUncheckedValue` methods to change defaults values like this:

```
$langages = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('languages', array(
    'label'         => 'Languages',
    'class'         => 'check_1',
    'name'          => 'checkset'
));
$langages->setCheckedValue('value_check');
$langages->setUncheckedValue('value_uncheck');
$this->addElement($langages);
```

And to recover your values:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    // isValid($formData) filled the form with the datas returned
    if ($form_duplicate->isValid($formData)) {
        // treatment
    }
    $values = $form_duplicate->getValues();
    var_dump($values);
}
```

Comment: It's changing but the main problem is that when i var_dump it, the box is unchecked. Even if i check it...

Comment: What i want to do is to verify if one checkbox has an certain value. That's my main problem. And i don't want to do that with javascript. I have to do it from the server side.

Comment: To recover your values, you can use `isValid()`, I precise it in the answer.